# how to delete windows? I only want ubuntu

Tags: windows

How can i delete windows? I only want ubuntu on my pc. I dont want windows. It came together with windows when I am downloading ubuntu but I dont want windows.
Is there any way to delete windows 7?
I am using ubuntu 13.04 please help me.

Please explaing me how to delete that windows 7

I tried to reinstall my ubuntu but my windows 7 still exist. I cant delete that windows 7. Please explain how to delete that os. I only want ubuntu on my pc because ubuntu is best os ever in this planet!

Answer (score 2):

Excellent Question sir. If you installed Ubuntu from a live CD there should have been 3 options "Install alongside Windows" "Replace Windows" or "Something Else". If you select "Replace Windows" (not verbatim) then the installation will use you entire hardrive, Destroying Windows while doing so.

Comment: I install from my portable harddisk. But I didnt saw any options for replace or install alongside. It directly isntall ubuntu without asking anything.